# Multiline string as argument for test template?

Tags: robotframework

I was exploring my options clean up my test structures and was wondering about the possibility to pass a multiline string to a test template.

Given something like this;

```
Templated test case
    [Template]    keyword that receives sql query
    SELECT * FROM FOOBAR
```

this ofcourse works but extending the query to multiline "..." syntax does not seem to help. For example;

```
Normal test case
  [Template]    keyword that receives sql query
  SELECT
  ...  *
  ...  FROM FOOBAR
```

Now, this would receive the whole query but each row as a separate argument. This can be dealth with by utilizing varargs as keyword argument and then `Catenate` the query into working one but the question is - is there a proper way to deal with multiline arguments ?